# Exchange 2010 to 2016 (Multi Site)

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, exchange-2016, exchange-migration

**My scenario:**

**Datacenter #1 — AD Site “A”**

```
* -4 ISP internet connections. (Outbound independently)
* -2 DCs GC (FSMO) Internal DNS 
* -2 DNS Servers - External DNS hosted into a DMZ (SPF / MX / PTR records pointing to Site A 
(mailflow))
* -1 Exchange 2010 SP3 UR30 with EDGE subscriptions. 
* -2 Exchange EDGE Servers in DMZ.
* -500 users

DNS Namespace: Outbounded model 

Mail services (DNS): webmail.company.com / autodiscover.company.com
MX´s: 2 mail.company.com | 2 mail2.company.com (2 on 1 ISP and 2 on another ISP for redundancy)
```

**Datacenter #2 — AD Site “B”**

```
* -2 ISP Internet connections (Outbound independently)
* -2 DCs GC
* -Plan to install an Exchange 2016 (Not yet installed)
* Connections: 1 VPN and 1 MPLS connecting Site A to Site B.
```

Do I need to install first Exchange 2016 as part of an Exchange Upgrade, and I need to install it directly on Site B (Not the main Site A) because it has more hardware resources and more employees. Can I do it?

**Questions :**

- 1 — Can I install Exchange 2016 directly in Site B without migrate any user mailbox?
- 1.1 -while Exchange 2010 SP3 still reside in a main site A, without changing, affecting or disrupting mail flow? Or needed to pointing the DNS records to Site B?
- 1.2 (ignoring the fact of the previous and immediate Schema/Ad/Domain updates from remote share in FSMO DC, and configuration of the SCP, the services and the SSL certificate)
- 2 — What's happens to the actual mail flow, regarding on that exchange 2010 cannot do proxy up to exchange 2016?
- Do I need to change all my internal and external DNS records (SPF / MX / ISP's PTR records)? To point to the second datacenter in Site B, (Exchange 2016), to don’t break mail flow, even though no mailboxes have yet been migrated?
- 3 — If I’m wrong, I need to firstly install Exchange 2016 directly in Site A where Exchange 2010 reside and change the firewall port rule to point to Exchange 2016?
- 4 — What about the 2 EDGE servers that already have a subscription to Exchange 2010 in Site A, if newly Exchange 2016 is in another AD site (Another Datacenter??)
- Can I remove the existing EDGE subscription to Exchange 2010 in Site A and recreate de EDGE 2010 subscription to Exchange 2016 in remote Site B?

Sorry, If I’m being wrong with all my questions, can you help me anyway for free with an orientation?
Any additional comments about my inquiries or the steps necessary to not cause any interruption are welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: You could read this doc and it would answer most questions:https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/client-connectivity-in-an-exchange-2016-coexistence-environment/ba-p/603945

Comment: Thanks, great article, but I really need to know if I can push Exchange 2016 directly to Site B, and not Site A or the main site where Exchange 2010 is located. 

and not only is that, but also exchange server 2010 has subscriptions against 2 EDGE servers. 

Thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: From my perspective, install 2016 on site A or site B are both ok, and those dns records don't need to change until you decide to move users to Ex2016. https://practical365.com/installing-exchange-server-2016-into-an-existing-organization/

Comment: But what happens with mail flow from recently installed Exchange 2016 ? 
I need to create an independenly SMTP send connector for outbound mail flow(and modify SPF and PTR for mail.company.com into de ISP to point to that site and public IPs), and from ActiveSync and OWA perspective cannot proxy from Exchange 2010 to 2016, so ?...i´ll need to modify all to point to Site B inmediatelly anyway, dont you ?

Comment: Hi Gustavo, I noticed you've asked this question on Q&A, you could get help there.
For your questions, I think you dont have to worry about breaking the entire system or something, after the new server installation, if you do nothing, then the mail flow will still hosted by Exchange 2010.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I was already able to install exchange 2016 on site B, without any interruption in mail flow or connectivity.